# Windows exe for ncremap nco tools

Tags: nco

I can obtain windows exes for nco tools from here: http://nco.sourceforge.net/#Executables but the ncremap exe is not available within that package. Is there anywhere else I can get the ncremap windows exe from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the other NCO operators, `ncremap` and `ncclimo` are scripts, not binary executables. Hence they only work in a POSIX environment, i.e., not from a Windows shell prompt, so they are not packaged with the other Windows binaries. As scripts they can be copied straight from the source code, though, e.g. [ncremap](https://github.com/nco/nco/tree/master/data/ncremap), and should work in a Cygwin or other UNIX-emulating shell.

Comment: thanks @Charlie, this helps since I could run these from the WSL bash on windows 10.

Comment: will be curious to see if that works. it could be a first...please post your experience so we can improve scripts for WSL bash if necessary.